# Why does creating an array using the spread operator returns something, while not using the spread operator the other doesn't?

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I type in the browser console `Array(100).map((x,i)=> i)` it returns an empty array as follows:`[empty x 100]`
But if I use the spread operator `[...Array(100)].map((x,i)=> i)` it returns all the indexes `[0,1,2,3,4,...]`.

If I am not wrong, using the spread operator creates a shallow copy of the newly created array, but I don't understand why the map works on the second version and not also on the first.

Comment: Using fill() you can find the indexes upto 100.

```Array(100).fill(0).map((x,i)=> i)```